# How to get a TEXT VIEW value from selected item in RECYCLERVIEW

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I  am  trying  to  get  a  TextView  value  out  of  the  selected  item within  the  RecyclerView  and  send  this  value  to  an  other  activity  .  My  RecyclerView  layout  file  has  two  TextViews,  one  for  the  firstname  and  the  lastname  and  the  other  one  for  the  email  .  i  found  that  recyclerview  doesnt  support  some  functionality  like  LIST  VIEW  ,  this  is  my  code  if  any  one  can  suggest  for  me  something  please.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.lab.Activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.lab.Activities.ModifyPers;
import com.example.lab.Activities.NewPersActivity;
import com.example.lab.Entities.Personne;

import java.util.List;

public class ApiPersListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ApiPersListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    TextView text1;
    Handler handler =new Handler();
String s;

    private Context context;
private List<Personne> list;
String nom;

public ApiPersListAdapter(Context context, List<Personne> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        }

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_api_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Personne p = list.get(position);
      holder.nom_pre.setText(p.getPrenom()+" "+p.getNom());

    holder.email.setText(p.getEmail());



        }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
        }

public   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView nom_pre,email;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nom_pre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nom_pren);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ModifyPers.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               Log.v("nom",nom);
               intent.putExtra("key_prenom",nom);

                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

}

}
```

Comment: Simply send as `list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNom()`

Comment: Where's your code for item selection?

Comment: what is `nom`? There is no variable named `nom`

Comment: There is in the view holder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `itemView.setOnClickListener`
 in the `ViewHolder` class , in the line `intent.putExtra("key_prenom",nom);`,  replace variable `nom` with this:

```
 list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNom();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in your class. Please have a look. Do implement listener in your activity

```
 public class ApiPersListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ApiPersListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
      public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
    }
     private final OnItemClickListener listener;
    TextView text1;
    Handler handler =new Handler();
String s;

    private Context context;
private List<Personne> list;
String nom;

public ApiPersListAdapter(Context context, List<Personne> list,OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.listener = listener;
        }

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_api_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
 holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);




        }


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
        }

public   class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView nom_pre,email;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nom_pre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nom_pren);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.email);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onItemClick(item);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on your onCreateViewHolder

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_api_list_item, null);
```

To get or set value to the textview of `R.layout.recyclerview_api_list_item` recycleview you need to find the view first so you can access them by the defined view.

```
v.findViewById(R.id.textviewID1);
v.findViewById(R.id.textviewID2);
```

Then return the view

```
return new ViewHolder(v);
```